# XML file not found on a correct location when transform

Tags: java

I was trying to modify an xml file by using DOM and this happened:
my code is:

```
public class XsltFolderWise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File curDir = new File(
                "C:/Users/rimancha/Desktop/SaveDir/11439"); // current
                                                                    // directory
        displayDirectoryContents(curDir);
    }

    public static void displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {
        try {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.println("directory:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                    displayDirectoryContents(file);

                } else {
                    System.out.println("file:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                    String XSLFILE = "C:/Users/rimancha/Desktop/SaveDir/jars/command-reference.xsl";
                    File INFILE = file;
                    String OUTFILE = "C:/Users/rimancha/Desktop/SaveDir/output_xslt/output"
                            + file;
                    StreamSource xslCode = new StreamSource(new File(XSLFILE));
                    StreamSource input = new StreamSource((INFILE));
                    File out=new File(OUTFILE);
                    if (!out.exists()) {
                        System.out.println(OUTFILE
                                + " created successfully? "
                                + out.mkdirs());
                    }
                    StreamResult output = new StreamResult(out);

                    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

                    Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer(xslCode);
                    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                    trans.setOutputProperty(
                            "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

                    try {
                        trans.transform(input, output);
                    } catch (TransformerException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Getting output:

```
file:C:\Users\rimancha\Desktop\SaveDir\11439\11439.xml
C:/Users/rimancha/Desktop/SaveDir/output_xslt/outputC:\Users\rimancha\Desktop\SaveDir\11439\11439.xml created successfully? false
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\rimancha\Desktop\SaveDir\output_xslt\outputC:\Users\rimancha\Desktop\SaveDir\11439\11439.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.createSerializationHandler(TransformerImpl.java:1220)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.createSerializationHandler(TransformerImpl.java:1062)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1270)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1253)
    at com.yogs.learning.restclient.XsltFolderWise.displayDirectoryContents(XsltFolderWise.java:69)
    at com.yogs.learning.restclient.XsltFolderWise.main(XsltFolderWise.java:29)
```

But my file path is correct .Not able to figure out the issue.
Anyone has encountered this problem or has a solution for it? 
Is my xslt had some problem or anything else.Please help me!

Comment: `C:\Users\rimancha\Desktop\SaveDir\output_xslt\outputC:\Users\rimancha\Desktop\SaveDir\11439\11439.xml` looke like an invalid path to me (note the C: drive location a second time...).

Comment: actually I have written sysout 2 times that  is why in error output it is getting repeated

Answer (score 0):

Here is your mistake:
first, you look up for file

```
System.out.println("file:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
```

It's ok, you've got it:

```
file:C:\Users\rimancha\Desktop\SaveDir\11439\11439.xml
```

But here you did something wrong

```
String OUTFILE = "C:/Users/rimancha/Desktop/SaveDir/output_xslt/output" + file;
```

I guess, you want add to out directory filename (`"C:/Users/rimancha/Desktop/SaveDir/output_xslt/output/123.TXT"`), but you add full file name (`"C:\Users\rimancha\Desktop\SaveDir\output_xslt\outputC:\Users\rimancha\Desktop\SaveDir\11439\11439.xml"`)

Sure it raise an exception, because ":" cannot be in filename on Windows.

Your error message actually told about it: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\rimancha\Desktop\SaveDir\output_xslt\outputC:\Users\rimancha\Desktop\SaveDir\11439\11439.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)"

Comment: yes..You are right .But when I have fixed this issue again I am getting following error: file:outfile is:C:/Users/rimancha/Desktop/SaveDir/output_xslt/output
C:/Users/rimancha/Desktop/SaveDir/output_xslt/output created successfully? true
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryIm

Comment: @RichaBajaj, well, but new erorr relates to xslt, but no files.